# Remove "proceed to checkout" button based on WooCommerce cart total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to disable and enable checkout according to the cart total.

Disable proceed checkout button works but enable it does not give the desired result, see the code below:

```php
function disable_checkout() { 

    $maximum = 500;

    if( WC()->cart->total < $maximum ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        echo '<p class="checkout-button button alt">Wholesale Orders is only valid on order more than ' . $maximum . '  Euros.</p>'; 
    } else {
        echo '<p class="checkout-button button alt">Proceed to checkout</p>'; 
        add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout', 1 );
```

Can someone guide me through this process?

Answer (score 1):

Some comments/suggestions regarding your code attempt:

- You can use the `woocommerce_check_cart_items` action hook instead
- Use `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total()` to get cart total. This is the total of items in the cart, but after discounts.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Setting
    $minimum = 500;

    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    // Less than the minimum
    if ( $cart_total < $minimum ) {
        // Notice
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'Wholesale Orders is only valid on order more than %s Euros.', 'woocommerce' ), $minimum ), 'error' );
        
        // Optional: remove proceed to checkout button
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10 );
```